# Crash while adding DataSets to a RDLC Report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dataset, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

When I try to add DataSets to any RDLC report within asp.net Project, Visual Studio takes some time (in wich it usually reads all compiled assemblies), and then suddenly crashes. It happens either in VS 2012 and VS 2013.

In some other machines, it does not crash. But does show any elegible class/method to be used as a DataSet source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please navigate to C:\Windows\Assembly and locate Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll to check the version number. For 2008 R2, it is 10.0.0.0 required. If no 10.0.0.0, install it by download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 ADOMD.NET and running Adomd.NET from:

[go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188441&clcid=0x409](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188441&clcid=0x409) (X86 Package)

OR

[go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188442&clcid=0x409](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188442&clcid=0x409) (X64 Package)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution myself.
First add the dataset to project from "add new item" wizard and then try to set rdlc dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in ASP.NET MVC project but in my case was from one Nuget package reference.

I found some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691720/2327332).

In my case reference that caused the problem was `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core version="2.0.2"`

After I update this Nuget package to `version="2.2.1"` solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what it did on the backend of visual studio but when I created a dataset it magically fix the issue on my report wizard and dataset creation in the rdlc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).