# Visual Studio 2013 Report Definition is not valid using RDLC report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, report, rdlc, reportingservices-2005

i cant build my reports anymore, i have no ides what might have changed.

i am referencing the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer\ dll, and still i get this errer :

```
Error 24 The report definition is not valid.  
Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' 
which cannot be upgraded.
```

i have tried alot of things, but just wont work (some links i used) :

[Visual Studio 2010: The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243754/visual-studio-2010-the-report-definition-is-not-valid-details-the-report-defi)

http://beatheadagainstwall.blogspot.com/2011/03/invalid-target-namespace-when-deploying.html

[Visual Studio 2013 Crashed While add a DataSet in RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426569/visual-studio-2013-crashed-while-add-a-dataset-in-rdlc-report)

if anyone can please give me an idea how to get this to work please help ive been struggeling 2 days with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

RDLC report was generated in VS2008 and you are trying to compile in VS2013 which is not a valid schema definition for VS2013.

Compile in VS2008 or upgrade you rdlc report from VS2008 to VS2013.